# how to convert number into string

Tags: php, string, numbers

I was wondering if its possible to convert a number into a string using php? Let's say I want to convert `"25,435"` into `twenty five thousand four hundred thirty five.`

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in PHP by default to do this, but you can quite easily find something by Googling for "PHP number to word".

http://www.krishnasrikanth.com/portfolio/works.php?app=numbwordter

http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Numbers-to-Words.html

Comment: Thanks!! I can use this for reference

Comment: PHP nowadays ships with [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/class.numberformatter) (did also back in 2011, you probably just were not aware of it). It has `NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT`. It's based on Unicode CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository).